# Is it correct to say "more apparent"

Tags: word-usage

In my journal entries for my English class, I am trying to describe the relationship the man has with his son in *The Road* by Cormac McCarthy by saying that

> ...the man is terrified of losing his son, which is *more apparent* when he sees how thin the boy is."

Is this correct?

Comment: Something can be or become more or less apparent, for some reason. However, it is not clear how seeing how thin the boy is makes the father's fear of losing him more apparent (than when? to whom?).

Comment: It should be noted that the context of the quote isn't provided.  If the father has not seen the son in some time and "loosing" implies he's worried for his son's health, it makes sense that seeing how thin the boy is might frighten him.   An observer's awareness of the signs of fright would make it "more apparent" that the father was worried.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks; but if there is no observer of the father's concern, then *apparent* is not appropriate; perhaps make it “terrified …, more intensely when …”

Comment: @AntonSherwood - The narrator is observing.

Comment: @HotLicks If it's a first-person narrator, yes; but when a third-person narrator says something is apparent, I take it to mean apparent *to a character*.

Answer (score 1):

**apparent**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/9518?rskey=zfOgAj&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Manifest to the understanding; evident, plain, clear, obvious;
>   palpable.

As in:

"The man is terrified of losing his son, which is **more apparent** when he sees how thin the boy is." Is this correct?

Yes, this is grammatically correct.